# BotFramework-WebChat Destroy all bot activity subscriptions on componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, direct-line-botframework

I am using the bot framework-webchat 0.12.0 version for a React App. I am initializing the Chat component with custom botconnection, creating a backchannel mechanism.

Does anyone know how to unsubscribe / destroy all bot activities in the backchannel?

When I inspect the network tab it seems that when I navigate with the react router to the view which contains the webchat component, a WebSocket connection is initialized every time and it stays open even after the component has been unmounted (navigate away).
I am afraid those web socket connections might become a problem if they don't get removed.

Here is what I am doing in my React component:

```
import { Chat, DirectLine } from 'botframework-webchat';
...
componentDidMount() {
    const { user, token } = this.props;
    if (token && user && Object.keys(user).length !== 0) {
        this.botConnection = new DirectLine({
            secret: configs.bot.secret_key,
            webSocket: 'true'
        });

        this.initBot();
    }
}
initBot = () => {
    const { token, user } = this.props;
    this.botConnection.postActivity({
        type: 'event',
        value: {
            accessToken: token,
            context: 'user'
        },
        from: {
            id: user.userName
        },
        name: 'conversationInfo'
    }).subscribe(() => {
        this.setState({ renderChatBot: true });
    });
}
...
render() {
    const { token, user } = this.props;
    if (token !== '' && this.state.renderChatBot) {
        console.log('BOTCHAT RENDER');
        return (
            <Chat
                bot={{ id: configs.botId }}
                botConnection={this.botConnection}
                user={{ id: user.userName }}
                token={token}
                resize="detect"
            />
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have spent a few hours searching trough the documentations and also reading trough the files and I can not seem to find a way to destroy those web socket connections when the webchat component get's unmounted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.